# Weather Underground 10Day Forecast API

Tags: javascript, json, wunderground

I'm trying to get a 10day forecast in my loaded10DayForcast function below but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'simpleforecast' of undefined
```

Seems like I don't know the correct api call based from this: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/forecast10day

Which is weird since I'm able to get the current conditions to be displayed correctly.

```
  //Get the current weather conditions

    function getCurrentConditions(text) {

    console.log("\n")

    var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
    doc.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (doc.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var jsonObject = eval('(' + doc.responseText + ')');
            loadedCurrentConditions(jsonObject);
        }
    }

    doc.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/"+ text + ".json");

    doc.send();

}

//Get the 10 Day Forcast
function get10DayForcast(text) {

    console.log("\n")

    var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
    doc.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (doc.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var jsonObject = eval('(' + doc.responseText + ')');
            loaded10DayForcast(jsonObject);
        }
    }

    doc.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/forecast10day/q"+ text + ".json");

    doc.send();

}

//Display to console
function showRequestInfo(text) {

    console.log(text)
}


function loadedCurrentConditions(jsonObject)

{

    showRequestInfo("Current Temp F:" + jsonObject.current_observation.temp_f);
    showRequestInfo("Weather Description:" + jsonObject.current_observation.weather);
    showRequestInfo("Icon:" + jsonObject.current_observation.icon);

}

function loaded10DayForcast(jsonObject)

{

    showRequestInfo("Today High Temp F:" + jsonObject.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday.Forecast[0].low.fahrenheit);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, you have a method called "loaded10DayForecast" in that you are trying to access an object that doesn't exist in the JSON tree.

I think you want to do this:

...jsonObject.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].low.fahrenheit...

Answer (score 0):

```
// JavaScript Document

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  /* Edit these variables */
  var api = "api key";
  var state = "Ks";
  var city = "McLouth";

// JavaScript Document  
  $.ajax({
  url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + api + "/forecast10day/conditions/q/" + state + "/" + city + ".json",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  success : function(parsed_json) {
      console.log(parsed_json);
         for(var some in parsed_json.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday){
         console.log("*************");
          $("#nxt10Days").append("
<b>"+parsed_json.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday[some].title+" </b> <br />"+
 parsed_json.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday[some].fcttext+"<br />");                              
 console.log(parsed_json.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday[some].title);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Next 10 Day